# Where to put audio isolation transformer?

Tags: audio, isolation

I tried researching (aka Googling) but I couldn't find definite answer on install location of an audio transformer.

[image]

Can I put this transformer inside the box? This is my preference. Or does the transformer need to be at the receiver end (ADA8200)?

Thanks!

EDIT: additional information

- module box is part of a headset with its own power supply (24VDC) thus requiring isolation to prevent ground loop. Behringer has its own separate power supply (230VAC).
- Mic and pre-amp have unbalanced output. Due to cable length, we plan to use LINE IN of ADA8200 instead of XLR (mic level). Should be no problem putting our unbalanced line level signal into balanced LINE IN of ADA8200.

Comment: What you are trying to do is a little confusing. Your mixere has enough gain for a standard microphone, no need for a pre-amp. If you have hum/buz problems you probably have a shorted or grounded wire. The transformer would be used to get rid of hum to isolate the components. It can go anywhere in the circuit, either end, whatever works for you. You could get an excellent microphone probably for less than what this would cost. More details will help a lot.

Comment: see additional info. Thanks!

Comment: So you're using the transformer to convert the unbalanced line out to balanced line in on the Behringer? In that case you want the transformer at the mic end so you get the noise cancelling benefits of unbalanced line.

Answer (score 1):

The microphone output is not balanced to ground. The receiver input is balanced to ground.

Is that correct?

A cable that is balanced to ground will pick up less noise than one that is not balanced.

If the transformer is placed at the microphone the cable **will be** balanced. If the transformer is placed at the receiver the cable **will not be** balanced.

Therefore the best place is at the microphone end. Inside or outside the box depends on magnetic coupling of the transformer with the microphone circuitry. To this all I can say is try it inside and outside then choose which is best.